# How to highlight every other line at gedit? (or better way to view log files)

Tags: gedit, log

I wonder if there's a quicker and more clear way to check log files at gedit. At least if it's possible to highlight lines alternatively.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Striped output helps reading long lines

#### Edit 2:

I found a dedicated tool, `ksystemlog`, to watch the standard log files. It might be the very best alternative to watch the log files. It highlights every other line, 'stripes' the text window and can do other things too. See the following links

https://apps.kde.org/ksystemlog/

https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-linux-log-viewer-and-log-file-management-tools/

and you can install it from the repository Universe,

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ksystemlog
```

[image]

---

I leave the other alternatives in this answer, because you might want such a tool for other purposes than log files, and the method with `sed`, ANSI sequences and `less` can work with very big text files. I know the viewer `less`, it works well for me.

And finally, I found **`glogg`** too in the second link above. It can also let you view very big text files, but there seems to be no highlights every other line, no 'stripes'. (You may prefer the GUI of `glogg` to the text mode interface of `less`.)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install glogg
```

#### Edit 1:

You can try with the following shellscript, that you may call `randig`. It uses ANSI escape sequences to render the colour and `less` to view the result. The file to view is entered as parameter to the shellscript.

Using also `xterm` and `sed` makes a better tool (than the original one), faster and nicer for the eyes.

```
#!/bin/bash

# xterm -fs 14 sets the font size
# xterm -bg '#2b2c2b' -fg '#dbdcdb' is grey background and white foreground
# ANSI:
# 'esc[33;40m' is yellow/brown on black background
# 'esc[0m' resets video

if test -s "$1"
then
 tmpfile=$(mktemp)
 sed -e "s/^/$(echo -en '\0033[33;40m')/;s/$/$(echo -en '\0033[0m')/;n" "$1" > "$tmpfile" 

 xterm -title "${0##*/} $1" -fa default -fs 14 -bg '#2b2c2b' -fg '#dbdcdb' -e less -r "$tmpfile" 2> /dev/null

 rm "$tmpfile"
else
 echo "
Usage ${0##*/} <text-file>

striped output helps reading long lines"
fi
```

Make the shellscript executable

```
chmod +x randig
```

and use it locally with

```
./randig file-to-view
```

or move it to a directory in `PATH` to use it 'anywhere' with

```
randig file-to-view
```

**Comments:**

- Line wrapping causes problems for the viewer `less`, so, if possible, make the window wide enough to show the lines without wrapping.
- You may need to install `xterm`,

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install xterm
  ```
- Please edit the font size and colours according to what fits your eyes best :-)

**Example:**

```
randig randig
```

[image]

#### End of edits

---

#### Original shellscript:

```
#!/bin/bash

blueback="\0033[1;44m"
whitefore="\0033[1;37m"
yellowfore="\0033[1;33m"
resetvid="\0033[0m"

inv=true

########################################################################
function doit {

ifs0=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'   
while read -r line
do
 if $inv
 then
  inv=false
  echo -en "$yellowfore"
  echo -E "$line"
 else
  inv=true
  echo -en "$whitefore"
  echo -E "$line"
 fi
# sleep .5
done < "$1"
IFS=$ifs0
}
########################################################################

# main

########################################################################

echo -en "$blueback"
doit "$1" | less -r
echo -en "$resetvid"
```

**Example:**

```
./randig randig
```

[image]